# Java List<> behavior

Tags: java, list, collections

I have odd behavior with a Java List<> class, which is overriding all values with the last one added.

Take for example the following code ...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class alist
{
    //   
    public static class item 
    {    
        public static String name;
        public static long   type;

        item() {}

        item( String n, long t )
        {
            name = n; 
            type = t; 
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "name: " + name +
                 ", type: " + String.valueOf( type );
        }
    }    

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<item> lst = new ArrayList<item>();

        lst.add( new item( "abc", 0 ) );
        lst.add( new item( "xyz", 1 ) );

        for ( item i : lst )
            System.out.println( i.toString() );
    }
}
```

I would have expected this to output the following ...

```
name: abc, type: 0
name: xyz, type: 1
```

... but instead it prints ...

```
name: xyz, type: 1
name: xyz, type: 1
```

... ideas?

I'm sure it's something silly, where I simply cannot see the forest because of the trees.
.

Comment: What does `static` mean?

Comment: Remove the `static` modified from fields in `item` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Answer (score 7):

You are declaring your `Item` class attributes static and thus, they are shared by all `Item` instances. Static attributes are class attributes, there is only one value of each associated to the class itself and not to each single object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

The second invocation to `Item` constructor is changing the values and that is why you are getting the same String.

Change:

```
    public static String name;
    public static long   type;
```

For:

```
    public String name;
    public long   type;
```

Comment: You should - given that you don't seem to need to change those values after constructing `item` - make the fields `final` too, e.g: `public final String name` / `public final long type`.  Also it should be `Item` and `AList` not `item` and `alist` (the Java convention is caps-case for classes).

Comment: You might (depending on what you are really doing) want to use an `Enum` instead of a `long` for `type`.  (Or even have different subclasses of `Item` for different 'types'.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Item class has static variables, not member variables. Each time you call the constructor you are changing the static value.

Change it to:

```
public static class item 
{    
    public String name;
    public long   type;

    item() {}

    item( String n, long t )
    {
        name = n; 
        type = t; 
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "name: " + name +
             ", type: " + String.valueOf( type );
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh! I knew it was something stupid I did ... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because you have added static while declaring name and type.
Static keyword only makes a single instannce of the object so whenever you update the value, it all values get the same.
Just remove static and try.

Comment: Thank you ... It was a yank/paste problem (you're I left the static decl in place) ... I knew better, I just couldn't see it for whatever reason.

Comment: your welcome. It would be helpful if you mark this as useful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the fields `type` and `name` are static, and therefore the same for all instances.